# Automatic command substitution?

Tags: command-line

When coding I often get errors in a certain line of a certain file. Often the output from compiler or processor has the format filename:LINENUMBER, e.g. `/home/math/foo.bar:60`. Since I use vim I then often copy the path with the trailing colon and linenumber and replace the colon by a space and a '+' character, e.g.: `vim /home/math/foo.bar +60` in order to open vim with this file at this line. So is there a way I can automate this? And what if filenames have colons inside their names? As I am only interested in Posix systems where colons normally not occur in filenames, I look forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You don't need to automate this yourself.

`vim` *already has* mechanisms to handle jumping to the appropriate source file and line.  Either …

- … write the standard error of your compiler to a temporary file and open `vim` with that as its *quickfix file*:

  ```
  vim -q errors_file
  ```
- … invoke your compiler from within `vim` itself using `:make`, which will automatically use a temporary quickfix file.

There's more on this at `:help quickfix`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile from inside vim by running `:make` and then you will be automatically moved to the line.

Comment: Even if the file is not opened yet?

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler output is in a vim buffer, you can move the cursor over the filename:linenumber and type `gF`. Vim will open that file with the cursor at that line. See

```
:help gF
```